# AngularJS cyrillic characters and get params

Tags: angularjs, cyrillic

When i try to send cyrillic characters as get params

[image: at first i was like]

They are transformed into that

[image: but then i]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal, use `decodeURIComponent()` to decode the url paramaters

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp